# Flaskdance doesn't generate a HTTPS uri

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to set up Google sign-in using Flask dance for a flask based website:

```
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
client_id= "CLIENT_ID",
client_secret="CLIENT_SECRET",
scope=[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
]
)
```

app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/google_login")

And as the documentation suggests, I have the view set up like this:

```
@app.route('/google_login')
def google_login():
if not google.authorized:
    return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
resp = google.get("/oauth2/v2/userinfo")
assert resp.ok, resp.text
return "You are {email} on Google".format(email=resp.json()["email"])
```

When I was testing I set the environment variable, OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT to 1 by using

```
export OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=1
```

And now even after I've removed the environment variable, for some reason the Flaskdance seems to always resolve the URI to a http instead of HTTPS.

This is evident from the redirect uri mismatch error I'm getting (here website refers to the domain name):

```
The redirect URI in the request, 
http://"website"/google_login/google/authorized, does not match 
the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

And here are the authorized redirect URIs I've set up in my Google cloud console:

```
https://"website"/google_login/google/authorized
https://www."website"/google_login/google/authorized
```

I tried unsetting the environment variable using this command:

```
unset OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution? It seems like flask_dance is sending http in the request and I have https set up on google Authorized redirect URIs.

Answer (score 2):

If Flask-Dance is generating `http` URLs instead of `https`, that indicates that Flask (not Flask-Dance, but Flask itself) is confused about whether the incoming request is an `https` request or not. [Flask-Dance has some documentation about how to resolve this problem](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/proxies.html), and the most likely cause is a proxy server that handles the HTTPS separately from your application server.

The fix is to use a middleware like werkzeug's [ProxyFix](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix/) to teach Flask that it's behind a proxy server. Here's how you can use it:

```py
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case adding this to my Apache VirtualHost config solved it:

`RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"`

My Flask is running behind an Apache proxy but Nginx would also have similar issues, potentially.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are behind a reverse proxy, you should configure your proxy to pass `X-Forwarded-*` headers, especially `X-Forwarded-Proto`. If you are using kubernetes ingress, you can set `"use-forwarded-headers" = "true"` in config map.

For example, here are headers that my proxy forward:

```
{
    "X-Forwarded-For": "10.0.13.1",
    "X-Forwarded-Host": "example.com",
    "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
    "X-Forwarded-Scheme": "https",
    "X-Real-Ip": "10.0.13.1",
    "X-Request-Id": "9cca69884ebe17e11faac3062b3dded9",
    "X-Scheme": "https"
}
```

2. Then you need to apply middleware with correct number of proxies that are used:

````py
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

#...somewhere here you create your app

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1)```
````